# How to turn off news/achievements of other players

Tags: runescape

I've restarted playing runescape (3), though I'd like to stop the news of other players getting 99 skills, all 120 skills, good drop,...

How can I set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your chat interface there is a megaphone icon. Click it to disable broadcasted messages.

[image]